# Turbolinks 5 working on feature tests with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, turbolinks, poltergeist, turbolinks-5

How can you config capybara to work with Turbolinks 5?
I already configured poltergeist, and `js: true` on my tests

```
RSpec.feature "Home", type: :feature, js: true do
  describe "on home" do
    given!(:user) { create :user }

    background{ visit root_path }

    scenario "can select user" do
      first('.header h2', user.first_name).click
      sleep 1
      expect(page).to have_content user.email
    end
  end
end
```

The only why I was able to make it work is using the `sleep 1`

Answer (score 2):

You haven't described what didn't work without the sleep, but I'm assuming it's that the expectation failed.  There is no specific configuration required for Turbolinks, other than making sure you're using a JS capable driver (which you appear to have done).

The most common reason for the behavior you're seeing is that you have `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` set too low, so the have_content matcher doesn't retry for long enough. Try increasing it by 1 second (it defaults to 2 seconds if you haven't set it to anything else).

The second possibility is that you haven't disabled transaction testing and are instead trying to share the database connection between multiple threads and are deadlocking.

Additionally, if you don't actually need to use `first` you should prefer `find` - `#first` and `#all` have a number of limitations  (doesn't wait by default and returned elements are not reloadable) that can lead to flakiness in tests, which make their use undesirable except where absolutely needed and you fully understand whats happening on the page.  You are almost always going to be better off scoping a find to a section of the page that only has one result instead of using `first`.  On top of that your usage of `first` isn't actually using the second parameter passed to it since it needs to be passed as a `:text` option

```
find('.header h2', text: user.first_name).click   #first takes the same parameters if you REALLY need first
```

Comment: this work without the `sleep` if i use `click_on user.first_name`. I but it doesn't if i use `find(...).click`

Comment: @Spike886  What do you mean by "doesn't work" - it does nothing? it raises an error? (if so what error)  - and `click_on` is the same as `click_link_or_button` - so it could be because that is clicking the actual link or button, whereas your initial example was just clicking on the `h2`

Comment: i doesn't wait the page to load, so it run expectations on current page before turbolinks remplace it with the linked one

Comment: @Spike886  Capybara doesn't guarantee to wait for the page to load on any action, thats why the matchers (like have_content) will wait/retry up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds.  If you increase that to something like 10 seconds and the expectation still fails (I'm assuming thats the error you get since you still haven't actually said) then either it's not actually clicking something that triggers a reload - or you have a deadlock because you're sharing a DB connection (you haven't responded to that either)  - or you're using ES6/7 features that poltergeist doesn't support